# Evaluating Erf[x] in arbitrary precision

Tags: special-functions, arbitrary-precision

Is it possible to evaluate `Erf[200]` with arbitrary precision? I only get `1.` as result but I would like to know if a arbitrary precision is possible because I need to compare a gaussian approximation to the hypergeometric distribution that for the values I'm using results in $\approx 10^{-6100}$.

Should I instead rely on `NIntegrate` and specify directly there my precision?

Answer (score 7):

For large arguments, is it not better to use `Erfc`?

For example:

```
myErf[z_, prec_:$MachinePrecision] := 1 - N[Erfc[z], prec];

myErf[200]
(* -> 0.9999999999999999...9999999999999531064070401639850196 *)
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring involved calculations at very high precision, allowing the answer to be produced almost immediately.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
1 - N[1 - Erf[200], 20]
(* 0.99999999999 <<17371 more 9s>> 99999999999531064070401639850196 *)
```

**In version 9:**

We can exploit the two argument `Erf`: `Erf[z1] - Erf[z2] == Erf[z2, z1]`.

```
1 - N[Erf[200, \[Infinity]], 20]
(* 0.99999999999 <<17371 more 9s>> 99999999999531064070401639850196 *)
```

Comment: My mathematica gives `N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50. reached while evaluating 1-Erf[200]. >>` and as result `1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
0`

Comment: Whoops, I'm not in version 9 right now. I'll update...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this gives the correct answer, but you could use `RealDigits` with a high setting of `$MaxExtraPrecision` to get your answer. Since it is almost 1, we subtract `Erf[200]` from 1 to get a number close to zero and add later:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100000},
 RealDigits[1 - Erf[200], 10, 10]
 ]
(* {{4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5, 9, 2, 9, 5}, -17374} *)
```

and then maybe

```
FromDigits[%]+1//Short
(* (200000000000000<<17353>>0000000937871859)/(200000000000000<<17353>>0000000000000000) *)
```

to get an exact rational expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps: `$MaxExtraPrecision=4999`
`f[x_]:=-x^2-Log[Pi]/2-Log[x]-1/(2x^2)+5/(8x^4)-37/(24x^6)`

`N[f[20],24]`          equals `-403.569343334317232747174`
`N[Log[1-Erf[20]],24]` equals `-403.569343334104234962969`

and `N[Log[1-Erf[200]],24]` returns `Indeterminate` but `f[200]` yields `-40005.8706948090821358531`
For what it's worth: `Series[Log[1 - Erf[x]], {x, \[Infinity], 3}]`.